# SparkAR Make network request without NetworkingModule

Tags: facebook, instagram, spark-ar-studio

Since currently, at time of post, NetworkingModule is not available, is there any other way of making a network request?

> We’re temporarily disabling this capability while we work to improve
>   performance and functionality. We'll reintroduce networking in the
>   near future.

Source: https://sparkar.facebook.com/ar-studio/learn/documentation/reference/classes/networkingmodule

Answer (score 0):

I guess they have safety/security reasons to disable this feature. While you are inside the effect environment can't do much. Everything else will be unwanted by facebook.

Answer (score 0):

All networking capabilities have been removed from SparkAR hub due to security reasons. You can't make network requests.
If you need networking capabilities for adding Videos I can help you out :)